# Error occurring in command promt while sending command for generating xslt reports

Tags: ant, selenium-webdriver

can anyone please help me on this .

I am trying to generate xslt reports using ANT and testng.

I amd using eclipse and have created the project successfully and all the test cases which is running successfully using testNG and reports are also generating.

Now I want to generate reports using ANT , for this I have configures ANT in my system successfully and all other thing (build.xml) are also running fine,
TILL , I type "ant makexsltreports" in command prompt  on this point it is throwing the below error in command prompt :-

BUILD FAILED
D:\Projects\Projectname\Selenium\Workspace\build.xml:111: Fatal error during trans
formation using D:\Projects\Projectname\Selenium\Workspace\src\testing\xslt\testng
-results.xsl: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/Projects/Plumsli
ce/Selenium/Workspace/src/testing/xslt/testng-results.xsl; lineNumber: 27; colum
nNumber: 72; Attribute name "data-pjax-transient" associated with an element typ
e "meta" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

now , this is the 111 line in build.xml file : - 
     out="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/index.html" classpathref="test.c" processor="SaxonLiaison">

below is the build.xml file : -

```
  <target name="makexsltreports">
            <mkdir dir="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output"/>

            <xslt in="${ng.result}/testng-results.xml" style="src/com/testing/xslt/testng-results.xsl"
                  out="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/index.html" classpathref="test.c" processor="SaxonLiaison">
                <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir" expression="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/"/>
                <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true"/>
            </xslt>
        </target>
```

And this is

Comment: The error message says there is a syntax error on line 27 of "file:/D:/Projects/Plumsli ce/Selenium/Workspace/src/testing/xslt/testng-results.xsl". This has to be fixed first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , Here is line 27 -                               <meta name="selected-link" value="repo_source" data-pjax-transient />                   and this is .xsl file which I have copied from somewhere else, it was working fine earlier , i generated the reports with the same file and now it is showing this error , can you suggest what should I add in this line

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this ...the problem was -- I was using wrong .xsl file , now I am using new .xsl file and it is generating reports and working fine....